# How to update a specific property of an initial state object using useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Consider that code where I need to update the state after some data has been fetched, I just need to update the data portion of the initial state (clientData):

```
 const [clientData, setClientData] = useState({
    data: {},
    product: 'profile'
 });

 useEffect(() => {
    getProducts(1).then(res =>
      setClientData({ ...clientData, data: res.data })
    );
  }, []);
```

How can I and is it possible to update just the "data" portion of the initial state without having to spread it (`...clientData`)

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You'll either have to use object spread or Object.assign

Comment: Another option is split your state with multiple hooks

Comment: Yes I thought of that, is it considered best pratice when using hooks? so you'd have `const [data, setData] = useState({data:}) and const [product, setProduct] = useState({product:'profile'})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, seeing that the set method returned from the `useState` hook [replaces the prior state value](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) with what ever you pass it, in it's entirety.

One possiblity would be to separate your state with multiple hooks which would give you a more granular means of updating your component's state:

```
/* Separate your state across multiple hooks */
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const [product, setProduct] = useState('profile');

useEffect(() => {
    getProducts(1).then(res =>
      /* Only update data portion of state via setData hook */
      setData(res.data)
    );
 }, []);
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer as it seems to be considered best practice!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of options...

1) Separate the following...

```
const [clientData, setClientData] = useState({
    data: {},
    product: 'profile'
 });
```

into...

```
const [clientData, setClientData] = useState({});
const [clientProduct, setClientProduct] = useState('profile');
```

and then you can update the portion of the data that you need to. This is probably recommended in the case you've listed above. Or...

2) use a library like 'immer' which allows you to create a new state tree by simply modifying the existing one...

```
import produce from 'immer';

...

const [clientData, setClientData] = useState({
  data: {},
  product: 'profile'
});

useEffect(() => {
  getProducts(1).then(res =>
    setClientData(produce(clientData, draft => {
      draft.data = res.data;
    }));
  );
}, []);
```

Immer is a fantastic library and you can learn more about it [here](https://github.com/immerjs/immer)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for useState. It's possible with [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) though.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, it is best practice to split this state between multiple hooks, however, it is actually possible to do this with `useState()` using a function like this:

```
const setClientDataSelectively = ({data=null, product=null}) => {
    setClientData((prevState) => ({
        data: data !== null ? data : data,
        product: product !== null ? product : product,
    }));
}
```

The parameters are defaulted to **null**, then using the **prevState** object and a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), you can check if something was actually passed in and attribute accordingly.